# Two lazy loading modules with common component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an structure like

```
---app.module
-------child1.module
-------child2.module
```

and I use 1 common component (`app-film`) in both child modules, I declare that one in `app.module`, but Angular still show error

```
Can't bind to 'film' since it isn't a known property of 'app-film'.
1. If 'app-film' is an Angular component and it has 'film' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-film' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/github/ms-dosx86/films

Comment: plz provide code on Stackblitz

Comment: This kind of error is shown normally if you want to input some variable to a child component and you don't have this variable defined in a child component like @Input() film: any;

Comment: @KrishnaRathore done

Comment: @GregorOjstersek variable `film` is defined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nested modules will not see that component which is defined in the parent module (which imports nested ones). You need to create a `SharedModule` like this

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [ AppFilmComponent ]
   exports: [ AppFilmComponent ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

export `AppFilmComponent` from that module and then import `SharedModule` module into two child modules separately.

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [ SharedModule ]
   ...
})
export class Child1Module { }
```

and

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [ SharedModule ]
   ...
})
export class Child2Module { }
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, but now Angular says `Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.`. That is in `AppFilmComponent`. Both child modules imported their own `Child1RoutingModule` and `Child2RoutingModule`.

Comment: You need provide everything what your `AppFilmComponent` needs into the `SharedModule`

Comment: even `RouterModule` that defines only in Routing Modules?

Comment: Yes, `SharedModule` is a separate module with its own imports

Comment: Wow, I did't know that. Thanks, I can see clearly now